# Question weight recount, does it retroactively affect daily limit counters?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit, daily-reputation-badges

Can anyone say whether the complete recount of question voting changed counters such as the one for the Legendary badge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it did. Before the update, I had only a single day of rep-capping on Super User (September 23rd this year), but now I have three:

https://superuser.com/users/442468/glorfindel?tab=reputation

[image]